# Jquery click function is not working in below code..?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <link type="text/css" href="App_Themes/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
       $("#myButton").click(function() {
          $("#datepicker").datepicker("show");
       });
    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table border="1px" >
     <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Text"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Date"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <input id="myButton" type="button" value="button" />
        </td>
    </tr></table> 
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my webform design code..

click function wat written in side script tag is not working...!! Anything wrong.??

Comment: could you please format the code?

Comment: @pvaju896 already edited it for you,,,

Comment: you are missing the init of the datpicker!

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair - you got that right... that's my answer below...

Comment: itworksproperly now let mecheck for my actual project with master pages..!!

Comment: BC30451: Name 'this' is not declared.

am getting one error like this..

wats the 'this' keyword gives..??

Comment: `this` is for c#. if you are working with vb.net you might try `Me`

Comment: oh k this is delimiter u have tried here ha,, ..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the documentation:

> show
>
> Signature:
>       .datepicker( "show" )
>
> Call up a previously attached date
>   picker.

so first of all you need to attach it!! eg:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var textBox = $('#<%= this.datepicker.ClientID %>');
    var icon = $('#myButton');
    var datepicker = textBox.datepicker();
    icon.click(function() {
        datepicker.datepicker('show');
    });
});
```

your you might go with the [icon-trigger](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger)

Comment: var textBox = $('#<%= this.datepicker.ClientID %>');

wat's this for..??

Comment: its working now the problem was - with initially i dint attach textbox with datepicker..

Comment: the `<%= %>` is for retrieving the actual rewritten id of the control

Comment: that's exactly what i've said: you are missing the init!

Comment: haha lol!.. I did not noticed your answer is almost the same as mine... +1

Comment: BC30451: Name 'this' is not declared. 

am getting one error like this..

 wats the 'this' keyword gives..??

Comment: `this` is for c#. if you are working with vb.net you might try `Me`

Comment: otherwise just the leave the `this`/`Me` out

Answer (score 3):

`.datepicker( "show" )` -->> `Call up a previously attached date picker.` but I can't see where you initialize your date picker.. call it like this first... `$("#datepicker").datepicker();`

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();

    $("#myButton").click(function() {
       $("#datepicker").datepicker("show");
    });
});
```

try to uncomment this line (`$("#datepicker").datepicker();`) on the demo

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5FhVb/)

Answer (score 2):

Add your script to the `document.ready(...)` function.

One reason it is not working is that when your script is executed, the `myButton` element has not yet been added to the DOM, and is thus not found. When using jquery, you should generally wrap your javascript code in the `$(document).ready(..)` to be sure the DOM is fully loaded when your code is invoked. Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myButton").click(function() {
          $("#datepicker").datepicker("show");
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: so shuould i give the script code snippet below those element TAGS..?/?

Comment: @Andreas actually it is a partial reason - his click event will not be registered if the element is not in the DOM. It appears there was more to it, but this answer is not wrong information.

Comment: that's why it does not state `wrong solution`, but wrong reason. i explicitly took care of your `the reason is...`, which is wrong - it would be the reason if the init happened...

Comment: @pvaju896 You can put a `$(document).ready(...)` before _or_ after the elements in question, since you are registering your function to execute later (when the DOM is ready).

Comment: @Andreas corrected the wording `s/The/One/` to be clear that this is not the only fault in the original.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code that has been generated. Is the id still called `myButton` and `datepicker` ? Often the id's are rewritten by asp.net unless specified otherwise and you are using version 4.

Comment: input element is not der,, ? is dat ok.?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use the client id of the controls, e.g

$("#<%=datepicker.ClientId%>").datepicker("show");